# How to validate akka TypedActor proxies created out of ActorRefs

Tags: proxy, akka, typedactor

The following would create a TypedActor proxy out of an ActorRef.

ITest proxy = TypedActor.get(actorSystem).typedActorOf(
                new TypedProps(ITest.class), actorRef);

Is there some way to validate the proxy, so as to ensure that it wont fail during invocation?

Comment: I think you might need to clarify. Any single piece of code can fail at runtime.

Comment: In the above code, proxy would be created but weather or not actorRef supports ITest wouldnt be validated. Only when I invoke a method, say, proxy.doSomething() would it fail and timeout saying "object not instance of declaring class". Is there someway I can find out that it really supports before invoking? something like a validation of the proxy?

Comment: It'd probably help if you included the stacktrace in the question. No, you can't validate the actorref, it could potentially point to an actor running on a machine on the otehr side of the planet.